# bouncy castle PGPObjectFactory nextObject returns null

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle

I am trying to decrypt and encrypt a message with RSA public and private keys.

When I try to read `PGPObjectFactory.nextObject()` i get `null` 
below is my code.

```
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        InputStream in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedString.getBytes()));
        JcaPGPObjectFactory pgpFact;
        PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in, new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());

        Object o = pgpF.nextObject(); // I get this null
        PGPEncryptedDataList encList;

        if(o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList)
        {
            encList = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
        }else {

            encList = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
        }

        Iterator<PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData> itt = encList.getEncryptedDataObjects();
```

the same code is working in `java 1.8` but when running in java 1.7 its giving this issue,

I am using all bouncy castel `1.63`

PLease help
THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case anyone has the problem, even though tried everything still not working.

for my case, its `bit size` as by default allows only `256` since my key bit size is `2048` its returning `null`

to fix this, please add `policy.jar` and `us-export.jar` in your `$JRE_HOME/lib/secuirty/` for `java8` you don't need to add.

if you want to check whether your java allows your bit size you can check by following.

`System.out.println( javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES"));`

Comment: in my case bit size is `2147483647`. and `java8`. But still getting null. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post stacktrace and source ?

Comment: Sorry, I found my issue. I am getting null because there is no blank space after pgp version line. PGP structure issue. If i put a blank space it is working

Comment: But i dont have line with version. What else can i check in my file?